# Microsoft Edge mouse input stopped working in web content after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: qt, mfc, windows-10, mouse, microsoft-edge

I created a window, which is always on top, inactive, transparent and click through, by setting the Extended Window Styles

```
WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
```

and the Window Styles

```
WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP.
```

I use this window to display eye tracking specific overlays or notifications at any position on the screen.

Before the Windows 10 Creators Update I could control any application with the mouse without problems. The mouse events were always received by the underlying window.
After the Update, the only application which causes problems is the MS Edge browser. The tabs and other controls can be clicked, but the displayed web content cannot be clicked or scrolled. When I close the transparent window the mouse input works normally.

**Question:** Is there an additional Window Style or other property that needs to be set, so that the mouse input will work with the transparent window on top? Or is this some kind of a new "security" feature of the Edge browser?

**Note:** I use Qt 5.8 to create the window, but the problem persists when using MFC. For those who use Qt and wish to reproduce the problem create a QML ApplicationWindow with the following flags:

```
Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus
```

and set the color to something like "#33000F00".
All applications should be controllable even if the created window is in the foreground except the web content of Edge.

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I need this answered. Thanks

Comment: i have the same issue in edge just on standard setup without qt

Comment: @ozhug I've posted this on the MSDN forums with a lightweight reproduction and hope to find a solution soon: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fe518a9c-e594-4bc8-8f00-1622527730d3/microsoft-edge-mouse-input-through-input-transparent-form-stopped-working-in-web-content-after?forum=winforms

Answer (score 0):

This issue should have been resolved by another Microsoft update.

We had the same issue with a windows forms application that we had made, however this dissapeared a few days ago.